# Link to a hidden jquery anchor from a separate page

Tags: jquery, anchor, hidden

I've used the code below to set up some scrolling to anchors on my site but I've run into an issue where I would like to come from a link on another page to a specific anchor that is hidden (section2). I pieced this together from some other questions/anwsers

```
var sectionhash = window.location.hash.substring(1)
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.scrollTo('a[name=' + '#section2' + ']')

});
```

but I can't get it to work.
If any one has any ideas on how to make it happen I would love to know.

```
var currentSection = '#section1';
var currentPos = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.drop_down').find('a').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var slidingSection = this.getAttribute('href');
    if(slidingSection == currentSection) return false;
    var slidingPos = jQuery(this).parent().index();
    var targetSlide = jQuery('#scroller').children().eq(slidingPos);

    jQuery('#scroller').children().not(currentSection).hide();
    targetSlide.show();
    var offset = 820;
    if(slidingPos < currentPos) offset = -820;
    targetSlide.css({top: offset});

    jQuery(slidingSection).animate({top: 0});
    jQuery(currentSection).animate({top: -offset});

    currentSection = slidingSection;
    currentPos = slidingPos;
  });
});


 <div id="scroller">
 <div id="section 1"> content</div>
 <div id="section 2"> different content</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain how it isn't working?

Comment: this is the error in chrome                                     Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
 } has no method 'scrollTo'

Comment: Surely you just want natural browser behaviour - namely that on page load browsers will automatically scroll to an anchor with the same name as the hash value passed in the url. No javascript necessary.

Comment: What jQuery plugin are you using to add the scrollTo function?

Comment: the plugin I am using is Ariel Flesler's ScrollTo [Here](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)               @Beeroot- I believe I need to use Javascript because the anchor's section is hidden.